# Невозможно преобразовать int в int [1024]

Tags: c++

Скажите в чем ошибка?

Необходимо было разбить входной код, взятый из файла, и переправить его двум процессам. Затем произвести вычисления с помощью функции, объявленной ранее, и результат передать обратно нулевому процессу для сборки и записи в файл. Выдает следующего вида ошибки

> `error C2440: =: невозможно преобразовать 'int' в 'int [1024]'`

Заранее спасибо за помощь.

```
const int m = 40;
const int SIZE_CONT = 3 * (9 * m - 12);

int rank;
int encrypt_code[SIZE_CONT];
int i;

MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
MPI_Status Status;
MCipher c1(m, 10);

const char *etalons = "etalons.txt";

FILE *enc_res;

int fa[1024];
int fa1[1024];
int fa2[1024];
int fa3[1024];
int fa4[1024];
int fa5[1024];

if (rank == 0) //Master begin
{
    /* чтение значений */
    if ((enc_res = fopen("enc_res.txt", "r")) == NULL) {
        printf("Can't open file.n");
        exit(1);
    }
    if (fread(fa, sizeof(int), 10, enc_res) != 10) {
    }
    fclose(enc_res);
    for (i = 0; i < SIZE_CONT / 2; i++) {
        fa1[i] = fa[i];
    }
    for (i = SIZE_CONT; i > SIZE_CONT / 2; i++) {
        fa2[i] = fa[i];
    }
    MPI_Send(fa1, SIZE_CONT / 2, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Send(fa2, SIZE_CONT / 2, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Recv(fa3, SIZE_CONT / 2, MPI_INT, 1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &Status);

    for (i = 0; i < SIZE_CONT / 2; i++) {
        fa5 = fa3[i];
    }

    MPI_Recv(fa4, SIZE_CONT / 2, MPI_INT, 2, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &Status);

    for (i = SIZE_CONT / 2; i < SIZE_CONT; i++) {
        fa5 = fa4[i];
    }
    //Master end

    /* запись значений */

    FILE *dec_res;

    if ((dec_res = fopen("dec_res", "w")) == NULL) {
        printf("Не удаётся отрыть файл.n");
        exit(1);
    }

    if (fwrite(fa5, sizeof(int), 10, dec_res) != 10)
        printf("Ошибка при записи файла.");
} else
    if (rank == 1) // Slave
    {
        MPI_Recv(fa1, SIZE_CONT / 2, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &Status);
        fa3 = (c1.decrypt(fa1));
        MPI_Send(fa3, SIZE_CONT / 2, MPI_INT, 1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }

if (rank == 2)
    MPI_Recv(fa2, SIZE_CONT / 2, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &Status);

fa4 = (c1.decrypt(fa2));
MPI_Send(fa4, SIZE_CONT / 2, MPI_INT, 2, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

MPI_Finalize();
```

Comment: сделал, немного правда коряво:(
Ошибки на этих строчках
fa2[i]=fa[i];
fa5=fa3[i];
fa3=(c1.decrypt(fa1));
fa4=(c1.decrypt(fa2)):

Comment: Соблюдайте форматирование кода.

Comment: Прошу прощения за поехавший текст.

Comment: @vladimir_ki Почему-то не могу написать в нижнюю ветку.
Как тогда сделать цикл чтобы массив fa2 заполнялся при выбранном условие SIZE_CONT / 2?
for (i =0; i > SIZE_CONT / 2; i++)
?

Comment: @rfry, Вы лучше (пока) русскими словами напишите, куда (в fa1[], fa2[]) и как Вы хотите переслать элементы массива fa[]. Типа, половину fa[] в начало fa1[], а оставшиеся в начало fa2[]. 

Или, как Вам надо ? А то из кода не очевидно.

Прочесть fread-ом текстовый файл в int fa[] не получится (fread() не делает преобразований типа). Массив будет заполнен "мусором".

--

Не обижайтесь, но IMHO Вам бы книжку по C сначала прочесть не помешало. Через несколько дней масса вопросов сама отпадет.

Comment: Необходимо прочесть fread'ом из текстового файла и присвоить данные массиву fa.
Затем заполнить массив fa1, первой половиной данных
А массив fa2, второй.
После этого уже переправлять данные другим процессам.

Comment: avp, а можно с Вами как-то связаться, чтобы задать пару вопросов?

Comment: Здесь и задавайте. Можно новым вопросом (топиком).

Comment: @avp Собственно вопрос такой, что в коде неверно написано исходя из того что написал чуть выше

Comment: 1) Вместо fread(...) надо написать свою функцию ввода fa[] c анализом размеров и правильности входных данных.

2) У Вас SIZE_CONT вычисляется, а массивы fa[], fa1[] ... всюду размером 1024 и нигде проверок на переполнение нет.

3) С fwrite() аналогичная fread() ситуация. Вы запишите в файл 40 байт из начала массива fa5[] в двоичном виде. Это то, что требуется ?

4) С MPI не знаком, поэтому оценить осмысленность аргументов Send/Recv не могу. Предполагаю, что Вы довольно лихо оперируете всюду SIZE_CONT/2 (**а что если SIZE_CONT нечетный ?**).

Comment: 1)А разве  функция fread не производить как раз чтение файла и занесение данных в массив?
3)По сути да, нужно записать в файл данные из массива fa5.Только целиком все данные полученные из массивов fa3 и fa4.
4)Данную возможность не учел

Comment: @rfry, если у Вас текстовый файл (т.е. числа в нем нормально видны в редакторе), то fread()/fwrite() Вам не подойдут. 

Если Вы храните в файлах **бинарные данные** (т.е. "слепок" машинной памяти из массива), то открывайте файлы в режимах "rb" и "wb".

Comment: А какой функцией тогда открывать файл чтобы затем присвоить значения?

Comment: Той же fopen. 

    FILE *input = fopen(in_file_name,"rb"), *output = fopen(out_file_name,"wb");

Только смотрите, чтобы имена файлов не совпадали (а то сразу обнулите вход).

У Вас сейчас исходные данные (числа) какие ?

Comment: @avp а как теперь произвести разбивку массива скажем хотя бы на две части?

Comment: Для начала читайте их в массив поэлементно в цикле (открывайте текстовый файл) и пишите так же (в текстовый файл).

    for(i = 0;  i < 10; i++) if (fscanf(enc_res,"%d",&fa[i]) != 1) { printf ("error in element %d format\n",i); exit(-1); }
    ...
    for(i = 0;  i < 10; i++) fprintf (dec_res,"%d ",fa5[i]); putchar('\n');

Надеюсь лишний пробел при выводе Вас не смущает.

Comment: > лишний пробел

    for(i = 0;  i < 10; i++) fprintf (dec_res, "%d%с", fa5[i], i == 9 ? '\n' : ' ');

Буквально на днях в одной публикации видел примерно это как иллюстрацию использования тернарной операции. Хотя по мне так ужасный ужас :)

Comment: N на 2 части LeftSize = N/2; RightSize = N-LeftSize; 

    for (i = 0; i < LeftSize; i++) 
        LeftArray[i] = fa[i];
    for (i = 0, j = LeftSize; i < RightSize; i++,j++)
        RightArray[i] = fa[j];

что-то в таком духе. Ну, предполагаем N > 1. Для M массивов сами пока подумайте.

Comment: Массив М - это массив куда будет записывать данные во время обратной сборки?

Comment: Пожалуйста, используйте опцию редактирования Вашего вопроса, чтобы указать дополнительную информацию. Кнопку "Опубликовать ответ" следует использовать только для исчерпывающих ответов на вопросы.

Answer (score 3):

Полагаю, что ошибка в строчках вида 'fa5=fa3[i]', т.к. указателю на массив присваивается значение типа int. Скорее всего должно быть 'fa5[i]=fa3[i]'.

Comment: если сделать так, разве будет правильно присваиваться значения в массив?

Comment: Да, будет по-элементное копирование элементов одного массива в другой.

Comment: Спасибо, кажется разобрался.

Comment: Теперь другого плана вопрос возник, должен создавать файл dec_res, в который заносить результат вычислений, файл не создается и результатов не видно, в чем может быть ошибка?

Comment: Скорее всего, код просто не выполняется. Вы в отладчике его смотрели?

Comment: Как раз на строчках, по которым были вопросы, при отладке программа застревает.

Comment: Проверьте внимательно все условия в циклах. Например, такой цикл закончится крахом:

`for (i = SIZE_CONT; i > SIZE_CONT / 2; i++) {
        fa2[i] = fa[i];
    }
`

т.к. i всегда растет и ее ничто сверху не ограничивает: `i > SIZE_CONT / 2`

Answer (score 2):

Добавлю, что всегда полезно, получив код ошибки, заглядывать в MSDN:

- [описание ошибки C2440 на английском языке с примерами](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sy5tsf8z.aspx)
- [описание ошибки C2440 на русском языке с примерами](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/sy5tsf8z.aspx)